# How to automatically close a program soon after it starts after windows logon

Tags: windows

There is a program that starts up shortly after I log on to windows and I would like to be able to close it after it fully opens/loads, or if that's not possible for it to close shortly after running.

Comment: 1)Have you researched any similar questions? 2)Tried anything? Many apps have a setting to not auto-start. 3)Can you advise which app this is? 4)Is this a work PC?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think to accomplish:

1. Startup script waits then closes process (you can expand script to CHECK if process is loaded with `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq iexplore.exe"`).

**HOWTO**
Copy below into Notepad, Save As with filename CloseApp.bat, move/copy to to *%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup* (run, shell:startup opens that location):
`REM timeout is a pause for 60sec or if you set to -1 it'll wait for a key press
timeout /T 60
REM taskkill closes an app, T & F say terminate child processes & forcefully terminate process
taskkill /IM iexplore.exe /T /F`

2. Task Scheduler script/command

Comment: Could you run me through one of those, please?

Comment: I've edited my answered, please upvote (up arrow) it if you found it helpful

Comment: Alright, I've tried entering the following line into notepad: taskkill /IM C:\Program Files (x86)\GIGABYTE\RGBFusion\RGBFusion.exe /T /F  and saving it as a batch file, but running it doesn't close the program.

Comment: Did you put that path in quotes because it has a space? If so then you must have the wrong EXE or there is a service that is automatically starting it back up. Use sysinternals procexp (Process Explorer) & target button (to right of binoculars) which can identify an app's location/path.

Comment: Just realized you specified a while path which you don't need to do, just the full filename. All commands have a help file: taskkill /?

Comment: I tried just using the full filename and that didn't work either.